# try-finally clause in Python behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, default

Edit: in retrospect, this is not a well thought-out question, but I'm leaving it here for future readers who may have the same misunderstanding as me.

There may be a lapse in my understanding of how try/except/finally work in Python, but I would expect the following to work as described in comments.

```
from sys import argv

try:
    x = argv[1]  # Set x to the first argument if one is passed
finally:
    x = 'default'  # If no argument is passed (throwing an exception above) set x to 'default'

print(x)
```

I would expect that the file above (foo.py) should print `default` when run as `python .\foo.py` and would print `bar` if run as `python .\foo.py bar`.

The `bar` functionality works as expected, however, the `default` behaviour does not work; if I run `python .\foo.py`, I get an IndexError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\foo.py", line 4, in <module>
    x = argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As a result, I have two questions:

- Is this a bug or is it an expected behavior in a try-finally block?
- Should I just never use try-finally without an `except` clause?

Comment: `try: ....  except:  ... finally: ....`  You do not catch anything so the exeption terminates your program. Quite expectedly.

Comment: The `finally` block is being executed but the error is raised nevertheless (since not `except`'ed).

Comment: You are confusing `except IndexError` with `finally`. `finally` _always_ executes, exception or no (unless the process is killed).

Comment: Reread: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: @Amadan: `finally` executes **even when you use `sys.exit()`, that's implemented with just another exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks. I shouldn't be answering stuff today. :/

Comment: D'oh, these comments make sense, I'm going to keep this question up in case others make the same mistake as me...and hope I don't get downvoted too badly...

Comment: There are reasonst to use `try: ... finally: ...` - f.e. if you get a strained ressource in your try by f.e. loggin into some service that needs explicit logout to free your "license" - you would wan't to put the logout in the `finally:` part. If exceptions happen - you get logged out and whatever happens with the exception ... happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. `try:..finally:...` alone **doesn't catch exceptions**. Only the `except` clause of a `try:...except:...` does.

`try:...finally:...` only guarantees that the statements under `finally` are always executed, whatever happens in the `try` section, whether the block succeeds or is exited because of a `break`, `continue`, `return` or an exception. So `try:...finally:...` is *great* for cleaning up resources; you get to run code no matter what happens in the block (but note that the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) and context managers let you encapsulate cleanup behaviour too). If you want to see examples, then the [Python standard library has hundreds](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=finally+path%3ALib%2F+-path%3ALib%2Ftest+-path%3ALib%2Fdistutils%2Ftests%2F+-path%3ALib%2Flib2to3%2Ftests+-path%3ALib%2Funittest%2Ftest%2F+-path%3ALib%2Ftkinter%2Ftest%2F&unscoped_q=finally+path%3ALib%2F+-path%3ALib%2Ftest+-path%3ALib%2Fdistutils%2Ftests%2F+-path%3ALib%2Flib2to3%2Ftests+-path%3ALib%2Funittest%2Ftest%2F+-path%3ALib%2Ftkinter%2Ftest%2F).

If you need to handle an `IndexError` exception in a `try` block, then you *must* use an `except` clause. You can still use a `finally` clause *as well*, it'll be called after the `except` suite has run.

And if you ever get to work with much older Python code, you'll see that in code that must run with Python 2.4 or older `try:....finally:...` and `try:...except:...` are never used together. That's because [only as of Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-341) have the two forms been unified.